# ServiceInstall does not successfully start mywindowsservice

Tags: wix, serviceinstall

I am trying to create a WIX installer that will install a Windows Service. For the Windows service, I create a service exactly how it's outlined http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp.

In my wxs installer file, I have the following markup specified -

```
    <Component Id="MyCompanyWindowsServiceComponent" Guid="*">
       <File Id="MyCompanyWindowsServiceFile" Name="SimpleWindowsService.exe" DiskId="1"
          Source="..\SimpleWindowsService\bin\debug\SimpleWindowsService.exe"/>
          <ServiceInstall Id="MyCompanyServiceInstall" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes"
                    Name="MyCompany:MyProduct"
                    DisplayName="MyCompany:MyProduct"
                    Description="MyCompany Windows Service"
                    Start="auto"
                    Account="LocalSystem"
                    ErrorControl="critical"
                    Interactive="yes"/>
          <ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                    Start="install"
                    Stop="both"
                    Remove="uninstall"
                    Name="MyCompany:MyProduct"
                    Wait="no"/>
    </Component>
```

and I have the component referenced like -

```
    <Feature Id="Complete" Level="1">
    ::
        <ComponentRef Id="MyCompanyWindowsServiceComponent"/>
    </Feature>
```

When I finally run my installer, I see the file has been copied to the right location but the service itself hasn't been started.

What am I missing?

Regards

Comment: Interactive services have been deprecated since Vista.  I'm not sure if they'll even start on newer OS's.

Comment: You may have edited that WiX to remove actual company and product names, so check that Name in ServiceControl is exactly that same as in ServiceInstall, just in case, but it's likely that it didn't start because it is interactive.